# Remove special character in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `String`, named a[1]. How can I remove "" to make the final output as below?

```
/data/user/0/com.xxx/xxx/ABC Home_2-2-2_12 Jan 2024-12 Jan 2024.pdf
```

Below is the code

```
var a = contentDisposition!.split(";");
debugPrint("eev ${a[1]}"); // filename="ABC Home_2-2-2_12 Jan 2024-12 Jan 2024.pdf"

var c = a[1].replaceAll("filename=", "");
var d = (c.trim());
var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

File file = File("$dir/$d");
String path = file.path;
debugPrint(path);  // /data/user/0/com.xxx/xxx/"ABC Home_2-2-2_12 Jan 2024-12 Jan 2024.pdf"
```

Comment: .replaceAll('\"', ''); still work without escape character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.replaceAll('"', '');`

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = c.replaceAll('"', '').trim(); // Remove double quotes and trim spaces
```

Add the above line in your code

```
var a = contentDisposition!.split(";");
debugPrint("eev ${a[1]}"); // filename="ABC Home_2-2-2_12 Jan 2024-12 Jan 2024.pdf"

var c = a[1].replaceAll("filename=", "");
var d = c.replaceAll('"', '').trim(); // Remove double quotes and trim spaces
var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

File file = File("$dir/$d");
String path = file.path;
debugPrint(path); // /data/user/0/com.xxx/xxx/ABC Home_2-2-2_12 Jan 2024-12 Jan 2024.pdf
```